# Is it possible to customize the 'CC' info to fetch data from each corresponding row in Google Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gmail-api, google-apps

I am currently using Google Appscript to send automatic mails. I have the option to include people in copy (CC), however, wanted to know if there's any way to fetch this data from each row corresponding to each person. Basically, each email sent should have different people in CC. I tried adding a code to get values from a column, but it's keeping only the first person in CC for all emails. I'm attaching a copy of the sheet as well - if someone could help me resolve the issue, it would be great (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NCl5hf0rfKMz-W7d2MVANgbxiDR2JsTqTS4XnNk4Rb8). Below is the code :: *var copycc = ws.getRange("E2:E").getValue();* is the line of code I have added in.

```
function Bday() {
  var slno = 0;
  var name1 = 1;
  var email = 2;
  var dob = 3;
  var copyc = 4;

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Full list");
  var wsSettings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings");
  
  var name = wsSettings.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var subject = wsSettings.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var copycc = ws.getRange("E2:E").getValue();
  
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:E" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();


  data.forEach(function(row){
    emailTemp.fn = row[name1];
    emailTemp.empid = row[slno];
    emailTemp.dob = row[dob];
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      row[email],
      subject,
      "Your email doesnt support HTML",
      {name: name, cc: copycc, htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

I thought that in your script, the values of `var data = ws.getRange("A2:E" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();` can be used for achitving your goal. And, the values of `name` and `subject` can be retrieved by `getValues`.

#### Modified script:

```js
function Bday() {
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Full list");
  var wsSettings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings");
  var [[name], [subject]] = wsSettings.getRange("B1:B2").getValues();
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:E" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data.forEach(([slno, name1, email, dob, copyc]) => {
    emailTemp.fn = name1;
    emailTemp.empid = slno;
    emailTemp.dob = dob;
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      email,
      subject,
      "Your email doesnt support HTML",
      { name: name, cc: copyc, htmlBody: htmlMessage }
    );
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of `name` and `subject` are retrieved from "Settings" sheet. And, the values of `email, name1, slno, dob, copyc` are retrieved from each row of "Full list" sheet.

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: I had a quick query on this - Is it possible to have variable subject lines? Like, each email should include the recipient's name along with the subject.. For eg, "Happy bday, Vivek"

Comment: @Vish Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Is it possible to have variable subject lines? Like, each email should include the recipient's name along with the subject.. For eg, "Happy bday, Vivek"`, in this case, how about modifying the above my script from `subject,` to `subject + " " + name1,`?